# Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I try to add an animation to a div using jquery :

```
$('#footer').animate({ "width" : "13%" },1000);
```

it works but an error is displayed in the console like:

**"Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported."**
[image]

when i click on the right link :

[image]

but when i use a value in pixel there is no error with :

```
$('#footer').animate({ "width" : 68 },1000);
```

is there a solution to use responsive values ?

Comment: I came into similar situation, and I think there is a bug on marquee tag for chrome. Hope this helps [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn6fe7no/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the way you call `.animate()`. You have jQuery added to your codebase but you are using the [web platform's animate](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/05/Web-Animations-element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36) with the way you have called `.animate()`. If you want this to work fine with jQuery change from:

```
var player = this.move_.animate();
```

to

```
var player = $(this.move_).animate();
```

but if you'd like to use the JavaScript animate over jQuery then you can have this

```
var player = this.move_.animate({transform: [parameters.transformBegin, parameters.transformEnd]});
```

I have no idea what your parameters are but my example shows you add the multiple key frames as an array for each property you are animating

Answer (score 4):

You fell into a trap. The `$` you are using is not jQuery, but it's a console's API, a shortcut for `document.querySelector`

This means that `$('#footer')` does not return a jQuery object but a plain DOM element.

This means that `.animate` is not jQuery's method but the element's method, so you're unknowingly using the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API), not `jQuery.animate`.

They have a different API and you get the error.

In short, make sure that jQuery is available on your page and/or use `jQuery('#footer').animate(et cetera)`

Answer (score 0):

works fine here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/ubgmvvyc/) with no errors

css :

```
#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

i think you get that error ( "Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported." ) because the element you want to manipulate ( `#footer` )doesn't have a specific size given before the animation

just give a `width` ( in CSS or inline ) to `#footer` and should work without any errors

let me know if it helps

Comment: thank you for your help. i'm making an example in jsfiddle to show the error. like this the problem will be more clearly.

Comment: the problem is with "HTMLMarqueeElement" like described in the comment of "terje" in this link : https://forums.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/175827/uncaught-notsupportederror-failed-to-execute-animate-on-element-vm7011-htmlmarqueeelement-js356/p1

Comment: well. without a specific example where you can replicate that error....i can't help you..